How to add a colon after each two characters in a string
I have a list like this:
list1 = [ '000c.29e6.8fa5', 'fa16.3e9f.0c8c', 'fa16.3e70.323b' ]

I'm going to convert them to mac addresses in format 00:0C:29:E5:8F:A5 in uppercase.
How can I do that?
I googled but found nothing. I also thought how to do, but still don't have any clues.
I just know this:
for x in list1:
  x = x.replace('.', '').upper()[::1]

I know [::1] splits, but not sure if it's correct and if I can continue with this or not.

Another way, using bytes.fromhex() and bytes.hex():
>>> [":".join(bytes([b]).hex() for b in bytes.fromhex(l.replace(".", ""))) for l in list1]
['00:0c:29:e6:8f:a5', 'fa:16:3e:9f:0c:8c', 'fa:16:3e:70:32:3b']

Naturally, if you need upper-case, slap that on at the end.
>>> [":".join(bytes([b]).hex() for b in bytes.fromhex(l.replace(".", ""))).upper() for l in list1]
['00:0C:29:E6:8F:A5', 'FA:16:3E:9F:0C:8C', 'FA:16:3E:70:32:3B']


You can use join() and range():
def get_converted(L):
    res = []
    for s in L:
        s = s.replace('.', '').upper()
        res += [':'.join([s[i:i + 2] for i in range(0, 12, 2)])]
    return res


print(get_converted(['000c.29e6.8fa5', 'fa16.3e9f.0c8c', 'fa16.3e70.323b']))


Prints
['00:0C:29:E6:8F:A5', 'FA:16:3E:9F:0C:8C', 'FA:16:3E:70:32:3B']


A different hex way:
[bytes.fromhex(s.replace('.', '')).hex(':').upper()
 for s in list1]

Attempt This Online!
